# progress event doesn't work properly

Tags: ajax, html, progress

I am trying to create a progressbar control for my ajax application. "progress" event is just fired when operation is completed. I am a little confused.

This is my code:

```
function send()
{
    var xml=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.addEventListener('progress',status);
    xml.open("POST","process.php",true);
    xml.send();
}

function status(e)
{   
   if(e.lengthComputable)
   {  
     var per=parseInt(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
     var progressbar=document.getElementById("result").querySelector("progress");
     progressbar.value=per;
     progressbar.innerHTML=per+"%";
   }
}
```

"status()" function is called just only once, when server responded.